# Can't write unknown attribute `challenge_id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My code is like this:

routes.rb

```
resources :challenges  do
   resources :problems
end
```

app/models/challenge.rb

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :problems
end
```

app/models/problem.rb

```
class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :challenge
end
```

db/migrate/createchallenges.db

```
class CreateChallenges < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :challenges do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

db/migrate/createproblems.rb

```
class CreateProblems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :problems do |t|
      t.belongs_to :challenge
      t.string :description
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

end

app/controllers/problem_controller.rb

```
class ProblemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
        @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:challenge_id])
        @problem = Problem.new(:challenge => @challenge)
  end
end
```

I can create a "challenge" with no problems, but when I create a new "problem", I got the error:

```
can't write unknown attribute `challenge_id'
```

At the line

```
@problem = Problem.new(:challenge => @challenge)
```

What may be causing this error?

Answer (score 2):

When creating a db table for your model that has a belong_to, use `references`:

```
create_table :problems do |t|
  t.references :challenge
  t.string :description
  t.timestamps
end
```

Also you can verify your database is setup correctly by looking at `db/schema.rb`.

Dont forget to run the migration either, simple one but I've forget on occasion myself.

Comment: The error is still the same. And db/schema.rb does not seems to create "challenge_id" either. Do I need to create a new migration to add this new column, or should rails take care of it?

Comment: Just to let you know: I didn't forget to run the migration :)

Comment: If you've already ran the migration, you cannot make a change to it and rerun that migration.  I'd either recommend, 1. delete/recreate/migrate, 2. create a new migration will add the references :challenge, or 3. unmigrate (aka it deletes the table) then change the migration and remigrate.